# Global class comparison with inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, comparison

I am writing global class comparison functions with `operator==` for a large framework where classes tend to inherit several classes or have deep inheritance (class `A` inherits from `B`, `B` inherits from `C`, etc.). In order to make things manageable I figured I would have a comparison functions for base classes and then classes that inherit from a base would use that function in addition to checking their own members

Googling around, I found example code for comparing classes but no examples that involved inheritance. Below I made up a simple example for base class `Foo` which `Bar` inherits from:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    int m_a;
    Foo(int i) : m_a(i) {}
};

inline static bool operator==(const Foo& l, const Foo& r)
{
    return  l.m_a == r.m_a;
}

static void coutResult(const Foo& l, const Foo&r)
{
    std::cout   << "l.m_a == " << l.m_a << ", "
            << "r.m_a == " << r.m_a << ", "
            << (l == r ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
}

class Bar :
    public Foo
{
public:
    int m_b;
    Bar(int i, int j) : Foo(i), m_b(j) {}
};

inline static bool operator==(const Bar& l, const Bar& r)
{
    return  ((Foo)l) == ((Foo)r) &&
        l.m_b == r.m_b;
}

static void coutResult(const Bar& l, const Bar& r)
{
    std::cout   << "l.m_a == " << l.m_a << ", "
            << "l.m_b == " << l.m_b << ", "
            << "r.m_a == " << r.m_a << ", "
            << "r.m_b == " << r.m_b << ", "
            << (l == r ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo a(1);
    Foo b(1);
    Foo c(2);

    coutResult(a, b);
    coutResult(a, c);
    coutResult(a, c);

    Bar d(1, 2);
    Bar e(1, 2);
    Bar f(1, 3);
    Bar g(2, 2);

    coutResult(d, e);
    coutResult(d, f);
    coutResult(d, g);
    coutResult(e, f);
    coutResult(f, g);
    coutResult(f, g);

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to work just fine but I was wondering if there was a "standard" way to go about this or a better solution. There are two problems I see with this solution:

- Every time a developer adds a member to some class they will have to know to update the corresponding comparison function but I can't see how this could be avoided
- No members can be made private and considering that the framework is large this is a problem. The only solution I know of is to make a getter for every private member

Comment: make operator== function a  friend function inside  the class  and keep the variables private example http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/94-overloading-the-comparison-operators/

Comment: @MAG, I had mentioned global (comparison function) because the alternative, member (comparison function), would not allow `a == b` in `main` as far as I know. In addition our unit tests tend to use equality macros in the form of `EXPECT_EQ(a, b)`

Comment: @MAG, just read your link, that is a good solution, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design has the potential to produce unexpected results.

If your `main` is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Foo a(1);
   Bar d(1, 2);

   coutResult(a, d);

   return 0;
}
```

you'll end up comparing a `Foo` object with a `Bar` object and output will be:

```
l.m_a == 1, r.m_a == 1, true
```

If you are happy with that outcome, you can stick your current design. However, I think that is an inappropriate outcome.

My suggestions:

1. Make `Foo` a pure virtual class to avoid situations like that.
2. Make `operator=()` a pure virtual member function the `Foo`. Provide an implementation in `Foo` the derived class implementations can take advantage of.
3. Implement the function the derived classes. Use `dynamic_cast` to make sure that you are comparing a `Bar` with another `Bar`, not `Bar` with another sub-type of `Foo`.

Here's a program that demonstrates those ideas.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
   public:
      int m_a;
      Foo(int i) : m_a(i) {}
      virtual bool operator==(const Foo& r) const = 0;
};

bool Foo::operator==(const Foo& r) const
{
   return (this->m_a == r.m_a);
}

static void coutResult(const Foo& l, const Foo&r)
{
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << (l == r) << std::endl;
}

class Bar : public Foo
{
   public:
      int m_b;
      Bar(int i, int j) : Foo(i), m_b(j) {}
      virtual bool operator==(const Foo& r) const
      {
         Bar const* barPtr = dynamic_cast<Bar const*>(&r);
         if ( barPtr == nullptr )
         {
            return false;
         }
         if ( !Foo::operator==(r) )
         {
            return false;
         }

         return (this->m_b == barPtr->m_b);
      }
};

class Baz : public Foo
{
   public:
      double m_c;
      Baz(int i, double c) : Foo(i), m_c(c) {}
      virtual bool operator==(const Foo& r) const
      {
         Baz const* bazPtr = dynamic_cast<Baz const*>(&r);
         if ( bazPtr == nullptr )
         {
            return false;
         }
         if ( !Foo::operator==(r) )
         {
            return false;
         }

         return (this->m_c == bazPtr->m_c);
      }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Bar bar1(1, 2);
   Bar bar2(1, 2);
   Bar bar3(2, 2);

   Baz baz1(1, 10.8);
   Baz baz2(1, 10.8);

   coutResult(bar1, bar2);
   coutResult(bar1, bar3);
   coutResult(bar1, baz1);
   coutResult(baz1, baz2);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
true
```

Comment: Thank you, the only change I see is that there are cases where `Foo` might actually need to be compared with another `Foo` and so I won't have it be purely virtual

Comment: @asimes, if possible, leave the base class as an abstract class and avoid creation of objects of base class type. Otherwise you won't be able to prevent comparing a `Foo` object with a `Bar` object, like I showed in the first part of my answer.

Comment: True, I agree that comparing a `Foo` with a `Bar` is potentially problematic but I need to be able to compare a `Foo` with a `Foo`. To be honest what I was testing now was removing the `dynamic_cast`, passing a `Bar&` to `Bar::operator==`, and dropping `barPtr`. As a result `Foo(1)` will be equal to `Bar(1, 2)` but there is less testing involved and two `Foo` can be compared